# RxJava - Trigger another Observable/Completable before complete and complete only after it

Tags: java, rx-java

I am not completely new to RxJava, but I am blocked with what seems to be a simple task.

I have a datasource that exposes a reactive API, all I want to do is to fetch some data, return it and close automatically the connection when there is nothing else to emit.

Here is my code:

```
public Observable<Object> execute(String query) {

    Single<RxConnection> rxConnection = getRxDB().getConnection();

    return rxConnection.flatMapObservable(conn -> {
        Observable<Object> rxResult = conn.query(query);

        return rxResult.doOnCompleted(() -> {
            conn.close(); // THIS DOES NOT WORK. I would like to close the connection and to wait without blocking.
        });

    });

}
```

conn.query() and conn.close() are asynchronously executed in different Schedulers.
This code does not work because conn.close() returns a Completable which has no subscribers. In addition, if I manually subscribe in the doOnCompleted method itself, the rxResult Observable completes without waiting for the connection to be closed.

I would like that the "execute(String query)" method returns an Observable that:
- Emit all the items fetched by the conn.query() call
- when there are no more items to emit, it triggers conn.close()
- completes only AFTER the conn.close() Completable;

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
Observable<Object> rxResult = conn.query(query)
.concatWith(conn.close().toObservable())
.onErrorResumeNext(e -> 
    conn.close().toObservable().concatWith(Observable.error(e)));
```

Comment: This seems to solve my issue in a pretty straightforward manner. In addition, it deals with possible errors too.
However, it is horrible that the rx forces you to transform everything to observable creating lots of useless objects.

Answer (score 0):

Resource closure is managed with `Observable.using`:

```
Observable<T> obs = 
    Observable.using(
        resourceFactory,
        observableFactory,
        disposeAction)
```

This creation method ensures that a resource created by the `resourceFactory` is disposed on termination (completion or error) or unsubscribe.

Comment: This is an interesting solution; however, I cannot make it working. In fact the resourceFactory does not allow to return an Observable but only a resource instance which is not my case.

Comment: the resourceFactory supplies a resource, the observableFactory creates an observable from a resource (created by the resourceFactory). @akarnokd is covering the details of your specific issue but you should be employing `Observable.using` to get proper resource closure.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to execute the query only when the observable gets subscribed to:

```
private Observable<Object> executeDeferred(String query) {
   // your original execute() method here, including doOnComplete
}


public Observable<Object> execute(String query) {
  return Observable.defer(() -> executeDeferred(query));
}
```

This will ensure that the connection, query and release happen only when the observable gets a subscription and not during setup.

Edit: you also want a doOnUnsubscribe / doOnTerminate, to close the connection when a premature unsubscription happens.